# Vue renders only the last registered component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

Vue always renders the last registered component, and only it. Even if I don't use it at all.

```js
//main.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.component('component-one', require('./components/ComponentOne.vue'));
Vue.component('component-two', require('./components/ComponentTwo.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app1',
    vuetify,
})
```

```js
//ComponentOne
<template>
  <h2>Component One</h2>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default class ComponentOne extends Vue{ 
}
</script>
```

```js
//ComponentTwo
<template>
  <h2>Component Two</h2>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
  export default class ComponentTwo extends Vue{
  }
</script>
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="app1">
      <!-- Whatever I put in here, it won't matter -->
      <!-- I will always get only the content of the last registered component -->
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <component-one></component-one>
      <component-two></component-two>
   </div>
   <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

What I get is the contents of ComponentTwo rendered on the page.
[Page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivlan.png)

If I remove the lines that register my components, I'm able to use component libraries like Vuetify inside the div tag, but not if I don't.
I expected to be able to use my components and any others any way I wanted inside the div tag.

Edit:
Thank you guys for the answers.
Is there a way to use these components inside the HTML element as I would in a template? Like so:

```html
<!-- This could be a index.html or, in my case, a Laravel Blade view
<body>
   <div id="app1">
      <component-one></component-one>
      <component-two></component-two>
   </div>
   <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Vuetify components works fine this way if I don't register any custom component.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question, I am going to say this will not work without some configuration on the Laravel side. A quick search leads me to believe it is possible but tricky. I read this post https://vegibit.com/how-to-use-vuejs-with-laravel-blade/

Comment: I believe it will demand some configuration from Vue side, it does not matter if I doing this from blade or a HTML file.

I've read this post, he used pure javascript, I think that's the reason he didn't have much problem, because it does not force you to have an entry point and use components exclusively from templates (I believe).

Comment: Yeah, typescript needs to compile first which could be the problem, so switch it over to javascript and see if it runs?

Comment: But it is being compiled first, everything is in the resulting app.js.

Comment: I got a lead! Since I can use Vuetify components the way I desire, I will try to register my components in a plugin and use it, the same way I'm using Vuetify..

Comment: Cool. Hopefully it works, as I am kind of unable to help at this point since I am unfamiliar with both Laravel and Vuetify. Let us know once you solve the problem you are facing.

Comment: I will. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well... it didn't work. The thing is not in the fact that it is being registered as a plugin, and I don't have time dive deeper into Vuetify's source code to find out how it does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a javascript main.js instead of a main.ts?

below is a standard main.ts app mount function. You would rename `#app` to `#app1`

```
import Vue from 'vue';

new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

This mounts the main .vue instance at which point will allow the rendering of whatever components you like. A small example below using some of your code and the helper [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) which is not required but you may find very helpful when working with Typescript and Vue

```
<template>
  <div>
   <body>
    <div id="app1">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <component-one></component-one>
      <component-two></component-two>
     </div>
    </body>
  </div>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
    @Component({
        components: {
            // This is the way to lazy load components, you could also just import them normally above the @component decorator
            'component-one': () => import('@/components/ComponentOne.vue').then(m => m.default),
            'component-two': () => import('@/components/ComponentTwo.vue').then(m => m.default),
        }
    })
    export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Check the comment I left for Caio. Is there a way to invoke these components from the html element?

Comment: @PauloPatez I do not believe this would work due to the vue template compiler needing to understand you are rendering a component and not just an HTML tag, but I am not entirely sure I understand what you are after either. Maybe add an update to the question with more clarity and I'll see if I can answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your main.js file, you need to specify the first component to be rendered, like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

Then, inside this first component (in my example App.vue) , you can import your other components (like ComponentOnde.vue and ComponentTwo.vue).

Comment: Thank you, Caio. The thing is I want to use my components inside the html element. I'm trying to invoke them from my server view (Laravel Blade). Or is it not possible with typescript?

Comment: Like this
```html
<div id="app1">
            <component-one></component-one>
            <component-two></component-two>
        </div>
```